# Angular Component or directive matching' jhi-product-list' element is out of the current Angular module's scope

Tags: angular, spring, intellij-idea, angular-routing, angular-components

I have 2 components
Home component which is Home Page
Product List component which will show me a list of products

Question : When I try to add product-list selector to home.component.html I get this error:
**Angular Component or directive matching' jhi-product-list' element is out of the current Angular module's scope**

product-list.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {ProductService} from "../services/product.service";
import {Product} from "../entities/product";

@Component({
  selector: 'jhi-product-list',
  templateUrl: './product-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-list.component.scss']
})
export class ProductListComponent implements OnInit {


  products! : Product[];

  constructor(private productService : ProductService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.listProducts();
  }

  listProducts(){
    this.productService.getProductList().subscribe(
        data => {
         this.products = data;
      }
    )
  }

}
```

product-list.component.html

```
<p *ngFor="let tempProduct for products">

  {{tempProduct.name}}: {{tempProduct.unitPrice | currency:'USD'}}
</p>
```

Home.component.html

```
<div class="row">

<jhi-product-list> </jhi-product-list>

</div>
```

And Thank you.

Comment: Do you add the ProductListComponent  to the declarations in your module?

Comment: Yes I did import { ProductListComponent } from './product-list/product-list.component';

Answer (score 3):

An Angular CLI library is configured in tsconfig.json to refer to it's build output in dist folder. However, dist folder is automatically excluded, which causes generated metadata.json files to be excluded from indexing. Additionally dependencies from such a library are not treated as direct and are excluded from scanning as well.

The workaround is to mark library output in dist as "Not excluded":The image shows how to exclude a folder

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1):

Such an error may mean that your current module does not see the component.
make sure you have correctly imported all your modules and components

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component and declaration that component in module like this:

```
import { ProductListComponent } from './product-list/product-list.component';
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ProductListComponent],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
})
export class ProductListModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me (see the original answer from https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-50597/Component-or-directive-matching-...-element-is-out-of-the-current-Angular-modules-scope#focus=Comments-27-6382028.0-0):

> When we create the agular library in tsconfig in paths, the path to the library will go through dist/*. But if you take components from projects/your-lib, then this error will go away. Hope it helps someone)

I have personally tried everything else described on this page with zero success. Nada. Refer to the attached picture to see how you can successfully apply the solution to your project.

[image]